# Submatrix out of bounds (OpenCV)

Tags: c++, opencv, roi

I'm trying to divide an image into a grid, and save the individual pieces. At the moment I loop through the piece number and get a sub-image, which I then save.

Can someone explain how to get the sub-images properly? I've been following similar posts on stackoverflow, but my code keeps failing an assertion which checks the bounds of the sub-image vs. the original.

```
int unitWidth = image.rows / n;
int unitHeight = image.cols / n;
for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
    //Take the next tile in the nxn grid. Unit is the width and height of
    //each tile. i%n and i/n are just fancy ways of a double x,y for loop
    Mat subImage = image(Rect((i % n) * unitWidth, (i / n) * unitHeight, unitWidth,unitHeight));

    ostringstream oss;
    oss << i << "_" << n << ".jpg";
    string name = oss.str();
    imwrite(name, subImage);
}
```

p.s. the first subimage doesn't break the program, but the second does (for a 2x2 grid, so an end piece). I've shortening the sub-image by 10, but that still broke the machine.

Comment: "i%n and i/n are just fancy ways of a double x,y for loop". Since `i%n==i` and `i/n==0`, and the loop iterates n times instead of the required nxn times, how is that a fancy doouble loop. Even if it was, it would be just obfuscation for no advantage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is your code fixed so that it breaks the image into nxn tiles.

Firstly you calculation of `unitWidth` and `unitHeight` is incorrect, and that is the cause of the assertion failure. It should be:

```
int unitWidth = image.cols / n;  // you had image.rows / n;
int unitHeight = image.rows / n; //  "   "  image.cols / n;
```

Furthermore, if you want an nxn tiling, you need to loop n^2 times, not just n times.
THe easiest way to do this is to just have two loops, one inside the other, one loping n times for the rows and the other looping n times for the columns.

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {  //i is row index
    // inner loop added so that more than one row of tiles written
    for(int j = 0; j < n; j++) { // j is col index
        //Take the next tile in the nxn grid. Unit is the width and height of
        //each tile. i%n and i/n are just fancy ways of a double x,y for loop

        // Mat subImage = image(Rect((i % n) * unitWidth, (i / n) * unitHeight, unitWidth, unitHeight));
        // I didn't understand the above line, as ((i % n)==i and (i / n)==0.
        // 
        Mat subImage = image(Rect(j * unitWidth, i * unitHeight, unitWidth, unitHeight));

        ostringstream oss;
        oss << i << "_" << j << ".jpg";
        string name = oss.str();
        imwrite(name, subImage);
    }
}
```

The easiest way to debug code like this is to make the Rect a separate object so that you can print out its x,y,width,height  and check them against the OpenCV assertion message.
Have you compile your code in debug mode?

```
        cv::Rect roi(j * unitWidth, i * unitHeight, unitWidth, unitHeight);
        cout << "(i, j) = (" << i << ", " << j << ")" << endl;
        cout << "(i %n) = " << i%n  << endl;
        cout << "(i/n) = " << i/n << endl;
        cout << "roi.x = " << roi.x << endl;
        cout << "roi.y = " << roi.y << endl;
        cout << "roi.width = " << roi.width << endl;
        cout << "roi.height = " << roi.height << endl;
        Mat subImage = image(roi);
```

Comment: This is the same thing, you just use 2 loops instead of my 1 loop. Using the code you put here, I get the same error. On the last iteration of the first row (the one where the rect touches the end of the mat) it crashes.

Comment: @Mirror318 this is not the same as your code. Your loop could only write n images instead of the n^2 required for an nxn tiling. Also `(i%n)==i` so why not just use `j`; and `(i/n)==0` so your code can only ever tile the first row. Furthermore, your calculation of unitWidth and unitHeight is wrong and that is what causes the assertion to fail. The code I posted has been tested and it works fine.

Comment: Right, the for loop was supposed to go to n*n. Anyway, the main problem was the values I had stored as width and height, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i = 0; i < n-unitHeight; i++) {  
    for(int j = 0; j < n-unitWidth; j++) {
        ...........
        ...........
        ...........
    }
}
```